# Firestore security rules check document key change

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-security, google-cloud-firestore

Are we able to check which key in a document has changed in the Firestore security rules? and then check against the object that has changed? I'm having a lot of trouble trying to figure this out. Very hard to test.

Thanks Ryann

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note: I learned that writeFields is not populated in all cases is not compatible with the rules simulator in the console. This does no cover the case for `allow create`. I no longer recommend this answer.**

`request.writeFields` contains a list of the keys of the fields changed in the request. `request.resource.data` contains the values in the request and `resource.data` contains the current values. For example:

```
// Allow an update if only the name field is changing and
// only if it's not equal to the current last_name field

allow update: if request.writeFields.size() == 1
             && 'name' in request.writeFields
             && request.resource.data.name != resource.data.last_name;
```

Comment: in the last line: shouldn't it be 

             >> && request.resource.data.name != resource.data.last_name;

Answer (score 0):

The new canonical way of checking which fields have changed in a document via Rules is by diffing it with the existing document:

```
request.resource.data.diff(resource.data).affectedKeys().hasAll(["a", "b", "c"]);
```

Comment: It doesn't work: request.writeFields.hasOnly(['a') == true;
            will not be the same as  request.resource.data.diff(resource.data).affectedKeys().hasOnly(['name']) == true;

Comment: Right, That's because `writeFields` is deprecated and has unreliable behavior.

Comment: Sorry, you don't understand me. The `writeFields` works as expected, and `...affectedKeys()...` doesn't work properly. I tried a lot with it without any result.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish but there are other methods besides `affectedKeys()` such as `addedKeys()` which may match your use case. As a developer for the language, if you have any issues with `affectedKeys()` then please let me know the specific failure modes so I can fix them!

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.MapDiff

Comment: I created a git repo with my test. Would you look at that https://github.com/OleksiiBrylin/firestore-rules .

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! It works! 

I suggest that you can add firestore.rules from pull request as answer, as it more extended way.